# How to get Facebook login status in Vaadin 7 on page load?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, vaadin7

I'm trying to build a Facebook login flow for my Vaadin 7 web application.

When someone visits the website I would like to:

1. Determine whether the visitor is currently logged in to Facebook and if so, get it's Facebook user id
2. If I find an account in the database for that Facebook user id, perform a silent login and redirect to some start page.

See also this [documentation about Facebook login status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus).

**Update**: I now have everything working, except I still don't know how to execute javascript automatically when the page is loaded/displayed.

```
@JavaScript("https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js")
public class AutoLoginView extends AutoLoginDesign
{
  public AutoLoginView()
  {
    testButton.addClickListener(event -> actionTest());
  }

  @Override
  public void attach()
  {
    super.attach();
    com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("reportFacebookLoginStatusResult", new JavaScriptFunction() {
      @Override
      public void call(JsonArray arguments)
      {
        handleFacebookLoginStatusResult(arguments);
      }
    });
  }

  private void actionTest()
  {
    String script = "";

    script += "FB.init({";
    script += "  appId : '<my-app-id>',";
    script += "  status : true,";
    script += "  xfbml : false,";
    script += "  version : 'v2.4'";
    script += "});";

    script += "FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {";
    script += "  if (response.status === 'connected') {";
    script += "    reportFacebookLoginStatusResult(response.status, response.authResponse.userID, response.authResponse.accessToken);";
    script += "  } else {";
    script += "    reportFacebookLoginStatusResult(response.status, null, null);";
    script += "  }";
    script += "});";

    com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(script);
  }

  private void handleFacebookLoginStatusResult(JsonArray arguments)
  {
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "status: '" + arguments.get(0).asString() + "'");
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "userID: '" + arguments.get(1).asString() + "'");
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "accessToken: '" + arguments.get(2).asString() + "'");
  }
}
```

I am currently using a button click listener to execute the javascript. But how can I execute this automatically when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution, which involved writing a [custom javascript component](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-7-loves-javascript-components). I also tried to achieve this with CustomLayout, but that never executed the facebook javascript calls.

The AutoLoginView class:

```
public class AutoLoginView extends VerticalLayout
{  
  public AutoLoginView()
  {
    addComponent(new AutoLoginComponent());
  }
}
```

The AutoLoginComponent class:

```
@JavaScript({ "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js", "AutoLoginComponent-connector-v3.js" })
public class AutoLoginComponent extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent
{
  public AutoLoginComponent()
  {
    addFunction("reportLoginStatusInfo", new JavaScriptFunction() {
      @Override
      public void call(final JsonArray arguments) throws JsonException
      {
        handleLoginStatusInfo(arguments);
      }
    });
  }

  private void handleLoginStatusInfo(JsonArray arguments)
  {
    String status= arguments.get(0).asString();

    if ("connected".equals(status))
    {
      String user_id = arguments.get(1).asString();
      String access_code = arguments.get(2).asString();
    }
  }
}
```

The AutoLoginComponent-connector-v3.js (*here you will have to adjust your package name and your app id*):

```
window.package_AutoLoginComponent = function()
{
    FB.init(
    {
      appId      : '<your-app-id>',
      status     : true,
      xfbml      : false,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });

    var connector = this;

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
    {
      if (response.status === 'connected')
      {
          connector.reportLoginStatusInfo(response.status, response.authResponse.userID, response.authResponse.accessToken);
      }
      else
      {
          connector.reportLoginStatusInfo(response.status, null, null);   
      }
    });
};
```